# The belongs_to Association in Active Record of Ruby On Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I HAVE THE PROBLEM . I NEED KNOW if exist some manner of use the following association to navigate from one class to another in an easier way

```
SCHEMA

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20140712054858) do

  create_table "customers", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  create_table "orders", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "customer_id"
    t.datetime "order_date"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

end
```

customer.rb

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

order.rb

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :customer
   end
```

My method of use

```
  2.0.0-p481 :044 > @customer1=Customer.create(:name=>"John")
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.6ms)  INSERT INTO "customers" ("created_at", "name", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sat, 12 Jul 2014 06:18:24 UTC +00:00], ["name", "John"], ["updated_at", Sat, 12 Jul 2014 06:18:24 UTC +00:00]]
   (162.3ms)  commit transaction
 => #<Customer id: 4, name: "John", created_at: "2014-07-12 06:18:24", updated_at: "2014-07-12 06:18:24"> 
2.0.0-p481 :045 > @order1=Order.new
 => #<Order id: nil, customer_id: nil, order_date: nil, created_at: nil, updated_at: nil> 
2.0.0-p481 :046 > @order1.order_date=Time.now
 => 2014-07-12 03:19:31 -0300 
2.0.0-p481 :047 > @order1.customer_id=@customer.id
 => 1 
2.0.0-p481 :048 > @order1.save
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
  SQL (0.7ms)  INSERT INTO "orders" ("created_at", "customer_id", "order_date", "updated_at") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", Sat, 12 Jul 2014 06:20:03 UTC +00:00], ["customer_id", 1], ["order_date", Sat, 12 Jul 2014 06:19:31 UTC +00:00], ["updated_at", Sat, 12 Jul 2014 06:20:03 UTC +00:00]]
   (171.1ms)  commit transaction
 => true
```

No exist some manner of to make  @customer1.@order1 and and map automatically?

Answer (score 1):

You can set up the reverse association from `Customer` like this:

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

So that you can create an `Order` record more easily:

```
@order1 = @customer1.orders.create(order_date: Time.now)
```

By saying `has_many :orders` in `Customer`, Rails assumes that the `Order` table has a `customer_id`, which in your case works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

**Association**

You'll certainly need to look up at your [ActiveRecord Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) -  your `belongs_to` needs to be matched by a `has_many`:

[image]

So your models will look like:

```
#app/models/customer.rb
Class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
end

#app/models/order.rb
Class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :customer
end
```

The reason for this is very important - when you create an instance of a model, you're basically instantiating a Ruby object. The `attributes` of your object will be drawn from the columns of your table, and, more importantly, you're able to integrate more objects / associative data by using `associations`

Using `has_many` or `belongs_to` creates a method which appends an object to your current / parent one - meaning you'll be able to call the following:

```
#app/controllers/customers_controller.rb
Class CustomersController < ApplicationController
   def show
      @customer = Customer.find params[:id]
      @orders = @customer.orders
   end
end
```